# Find all x where that limit is true

Tags: nested-radicals

Let the following expression, with $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$ T_n = \underbrace{\sqrt{x \sqrt{x \sqrt{x \dots \sqrt{x}}}}}_{\text{n times}} $$

It's easy to see that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} T_n = x$$

Find all x where that limit is true

Comment: What do you mean by 'assigning a numerical set for $x$'?

Comment: I do not know what you mean, by assign a numerical set, do you mean find all x where that limit is true? What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: yes Bill Trok, sorry i'm not used to write math in english.

Comment: What i'm trying to say is: is this valid for N, R, or C?

Comment: The relation $T_{n+1} = \sqrt{xT_n}$ together with induction can be useful to determine this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may observe that
$$ T_n = \underbrace{\sqrt{x \sqrt{x \sqrt{x \dots \sqrt{x}}}}}_{\text{n times}}=x^{\large \frac12+\frac1{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}}=x^{\large 1-\frac{1}{2^n}}.$$ Hence for **any complex number with non negative real part** $x$ you have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} T_n = x.$$

Comment: $x=0$ too ... and (if we use the principal square roots) any complex number with nonnegative real part.

Comment: @kobe For me "positive" doesn't mean "strictly positive". Does it?

Comment: In English, "positive" means $>0$. This is distinct from the French word "positif" which means $\ge 0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ok, thanks.

Comment: The "hence" doesn't quite follow in the case of complex $x$; there a more ad-hoc argument is needed.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't see the point since in the complex case you have $\displaystyle x^{\large 1-\frac{1}{2^n}}=exp\left((1-\frac{1}{2^n})\log x\right)$ with $\Re x > 0$ giving the conclusion (for $x=0$, the result being direct).

Comment: x @Olivier: Not so fast. Significantly more than that is needed to argue that the multi-valued nature of the complex square roots and logarithms will not create problems. As one example, the straightforward derivation of $x^{1-2^{-n}}$ that works in the real case depends on the rule $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a \sqrt b$ -- but that isn't true in general for complex numbers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Of course it is not true in general, but here we have considered the principal value of the logarithm.

Comment: x @Olivier: Just because it's _true_ doesn't mean that you have presented a convincing argument that it is.